# print("Hello World") returns no output in iPython

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am starting out in Spyder 3.3.3, Python 3.7.  Basically a print("whatever") returns no output. It worked before, then it no longer functioned, not sure why. See below.

```
In [32]: print("hello world")

In [33]:
```

I should see

```
Out [32] hello world
```

but I don't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`print("hello world")` returns None and prints at stdout, the interactive shell prints the `repr()` of the return value, in no version of Python/IPython would it ever produce `Out [32]: hello world`. Rather, what normally happens is that it just outputs `hello world` (no output markers, and `str()` instead of `repr()`) because the stdout of the shell and the stdout of the program is usually connected to the same terminal.

If the stdout of the program doesn't match the stdout of the shell, which might happen if you have unusual redirections, then the print output might have gone to somewhere else.

Comment: I figured stdout was redirected elsewhere. Initially it worked.  Actually, I was writing some functions etc and it was fine, then it started failing so I went straight to the console and it failed also.  How do I find out where stdout is redirected to? And what is the proper syntax to set it back to the console?  And how in the heck do you do a carriage return in this comment interface.  Good lord, I am struggling with the simple stuff!  THANK YOU

Comment: I reinstalled Anaconda and it fixed it. Mods can mark this as complete. I suspect it was just an option I configured wrong but I never could figure it out.